# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in Tagsinput/typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I have an issue with my typeahead/tagsinput input-field. It worked before, and then suddenly stopped working, i did not touch any of the Javascript.

I have an input field like so:

```
<div class="form-group select_city">
    <label for="city_name" class=" required">Ort/kommun <span class="redstar">*</span></label><br/>
    <input class="form-control typeahead" id="city_name" type="text" placeholder="Ort/kommun" name="city_name">
</div>
```

And my javascript:

```
var cities = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('city_name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: 'http://laravel.dev/data/cities',
        remote: {
            url: 'http://laravel.dev/data/cities/%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

$('.select_city .typeahead').tagsinput({
        itemValue: 'id',
        itemText: 'city_name',
        typeaheadjs: {
            source: cities,
            name: 'city_name',
            display: 'city_name',
            items: 1000,
            minLength: 0
        }
    });
```

From the 'url' i route it tho the following method which gets the data properly:

```
public function get_cities($query = "")
{
    $cities = City::select('city_name', 'id')->where('city_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();
    return \Response::json($cities);
}
```

If i check the url and put in a parameter of "stockholm" for example, i get data like this:

```
[{"city_name":"Stockholm","id":861}]
```

This is all correct, and the issue lies where im setting the 'itemValue' in the tagsinput part of the javascript. Everything works fine until i try to put the 'id' there, it works if i have the city_name instead, and it worked before with the id so i cannot really figure out where something has went wrong.. I have another tagsinput field that is built exactly the same, but everything works there.

The error occurs when i write in the field and typeahead makes a suggestion and i click it, so it is the tagsinput that fails when trying to set the itemValue.